# Struct to an array

Tags: c#, arrays, struct

As the title states, what I want to do is transform this:

```
public struct name 
{
   public float var1;
   public float var2;
   public float var3;
}
```

to an array.

As you can see they are all float types, and I can access them using the var name. I want to do the same using an array. Is it possible to add these 3 variables in an array? My main purpose is to use foreach iteration on these variables, as in this case I have like 9 variables so it would've been easier to use an array, I suppose..

Comment: `var yourFloats = new[]{i.var1, i.var2, i.var3};` where `i` is an instance of the struct `name`.

Comment: So what problems are you having putting those values into an array?

Comment: @Servy not entirely trying to copy var's values to an array, but just create an array with possibly 3 different names in which I am able to have float values.

Comment: @Bips04 If you want to know how to create an array with 3 possible values you can do a quick web search on "how to create an array in C#" and it should show you how to do that.  Did you run into any problems trying to find a solution or using any of the solutions you found?

Comment: I'm aware of how to create an array, what I wished was different. For example, have an array of string and float? String for the name of the var and float for that string's value. Much like dictionary list, I suppose...

Comment: @Bips04: It sounds like what you want is in fact *not* an array then. Perhaps you could explain what you want to do, what properties you want this thing to have. I think you are confusing things by saying you want an array and then saying you want it to do things that an array doesn't do.

Comment: It sounds like what you need is a `Dictionary<string, float>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is a dictionary:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, float>();
dictionary.Add("var1", 5);
dictionary.Add("var2", 6);
dictionary.Add("var3", 7);
dictionary.Add("var4", 8);

var value1 = dictionary["var1"]; //5
var value2 = dictionary["var2"]; //6
var value3 = dictionary["var3"]; //7
var value4 = dictionary["var4"]; //8
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
float[] myArray = new float[3];

myArray[0] = var1;
myArray[1] = var2;
myArray[2] = var3;

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++;)
{
   // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Could be, but not what I intended, what I wanted to do was not to copy var's values but create an array with 3 different names in which I am able to have float values.

Comment: Arrays use indexes, not names. Are you looking for something like a dictionary?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
var a = new name();
a.var1 = 1;
a.var2 = 2;
a.var3 = 4;
var ls = a.GetType().GetFields().Select(x => x.GetValue(a)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have made my `struct` work as arrays also. I implemented `IEnumerable<float>`. For example:

```
public struct Vector3 : IEnumerable<float>
{
    // Remember mutable structs are evil. 
    // Always make fields readonly if possible.
    public readonly float x;
    public readonly float y;
    public readonly float z;

    public Vector3(float x, float y, float z)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }

    public IEnumerator<float> GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return x;
        yield return y;
        yield return z;
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Vector3 a = new Vector3(2f, -1f, 3f);
        // This uses `Enumerable.ToArray()`
        float[] vals = a.ToArray();
        // This uses `Enumerable.Sum()`
        float sum = a.Sum();
        // This iterates through the values in `a`
        foreach (var item in a)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A different answer, with an example:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct Vertex 
{
  [FieldOffset(0)]
  public Single X;
  [FieldOffset(4)] // Single uses 4 bytes
  public Single Y;
  [FieldOffset(8)]
  public Single Z;
  [FieldOffset(0)] // This points to the start of the array :)
  public Single[] Position;
}
```

Also, you can use other structs, instead of properties:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct Vertex 
{
  [FieldOffset(0)]
  public Single X;
  [FieldOffset(4)] // Single uses 4 bytes
  public Single Y;
  [FieldOffset(8)]
  public Single Z;
  [FieldOffset(0)] // This points to the start of the array :)
  public Position Position;
}
public stuct Position
{
  public Single X, Y, Z;
}
```

And then use `myVertex.Position[0] // X`, for example